# MacBook Air Running Yosemite - Merge Two User Accounts?

Tags: macos, user-account, migration, pc

I am brand new to Mac.  I very recently migrated all of my files from my Windows PC.

When setting up my MacBook Air initially, I was instructed to create a user account.  When I migrated my files from the Windows PC, it created an entirely separate account.

Is there a process to combine the two together or possibly migrate files from one to the other and delete one account?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you migrate from Windows PC?

Comment: Ahh - I did the same thing recently. Given the offer of Migrating now or later, I chose later... I ended up trashing one account & just using the other. (Won't make that mistake again ;)  Would be interested to hear of a way, but I don't think there is one, other than manually copying data from one to the other.

Comment: tetsujin is correct (as he usually is) Combining two user accounts is nothing more than copying the files you want from one to the other. Having never used the Apple migration tool (Windows to Mac) I'm not sure how, exactly, it works, but I do believe it creates a new user profile based on the one(s) you copied from the PC.

Answer (score 1):

- From your main account open Finder and locate the user account for your pc files. (Macintosh HD/users/pcfiles)
- Right or control click on that folder and select Get Info.
- Under Sharing and Permissions click on the lock icon to unlock permissions.  Give admin password when asked.
- Once unlocked, click on the + button and add your main ID to the user names
- Set your permissions to Read & Write.
- Click on the gear icon and make your main ID the "owner" of the folder.
- Click on the gear again and apply to enclosed items.
- Click on the lock icon to re-lock the folder.

Your main ID now owns the pc files.  You should be able to move files or folders to your main id file structure (no need to copy) or just access them as is.  You could import directly into iTunes or iPhoto etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to macOS, I don't recommend to customize file or folder permissions.

- Simply collect all files and folders you would like to merge in a new user account.
- Move of them to Macintosh HD > Users > your-new-user > Public > Dropbox. All files and folder will be copied to the new user account. Depending on the file size this process requires some time.
- Go to the Apple menu > log out
- Login with your macOS user
- Now, In Finder go to Macintosh HD > Users > your-new-user > Public > Dropbox and move your files to your preferred location e.g pictures, music and so on.

If you have successfully copied all files, you can delete your previous user account. Open System Preferences > Users & Groups. Note, please double check your files!! Make sure you have created a backup before deleting! You have been warned!